Boon of combat prowess when you can only attack once
If I'm playing as a life cleric, and I get the feat "Boon of Combat Prowess", does that basically mean "if you miss, actually no you don't", assuming I don't use a bonus action or reaction to attack?
It reads:

Peerless Aim. When you miss with an attack roll, you can hit instead. Once you use this benefit, you can't use it again until the start of your next turn.


Yes, you have interpreted the description of the "Peerless Aim" benefit of the Boon of Combat Prowess feat correctly. A cleric may choose any Epic Boon feat when they reach level 19, including the Boon of Combat Prowess.
In addition, there is nothing that says you cannot use this benefit when you attack with a bonus action or a reaction, if you are able to do so.
I did notice that the spell inflict wounds has been changed so that it no longer uses an attack roll, or deals as much damage as it used to, perhaps making this feat less tempting for a cleric to take.

It would apply to any other spell with an attack roll, though looking through the 2024 list, Guiding Bolt might be the only other one Clerics have now? Maybe Spiritual Weapon.

Yeah, I was specifying the bonus action and reaction because I can only use it once per turn, so if I use all three to attack I can only affect one

@Tasi you only need it when you miss. so having more attacks is still good. You should be expecting to hit more often than not
